# Remove Whitespaces in an xml tag using ElementTree in python 2.6

Tags: python, xml-parsing, whitespace, removechild

I want to remove the whitespaces inside the Enum tags. They are actually new lines(^$). I got them after removing the children nodes inside Enum tags using ElemntTree.

```
 <Enum name="Coupon Type" group="" defaultVal=""> </Enum>
 <Enum name="DayCountConvention" group="" defaultVal=""> </Enum>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the  elements and set the `text` attribute to `None`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

SOURCE = '''\
<root>
    <Enum name="Coupon Type" group="" defaultVal=""> </Enum>
    <Enum name="DayCountConvention" group="" defaultVal=""> </Enum>
</root>
'''

def main():
    root_node = etree.fromstring(SOURCE)
    for enum_node in root_node.findall('Enum'):
        enum_node.text = None
    print etree.tostring(root_node)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```xml
<root>
    <Enum defaultVal="" group="" name="Coupon Type" />
    <Enum defaultVal="" group="" name="DayCountConvention" />
</root>
```

If there are  elements still containing content you might want to test that and just set the `text` of empty  elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. It solved a problem that I've been struggling for a couple of days.